# Docker same image but workings in different way

Tags: bash, docker, deployment, bitbucket, symfony

I need to create a deployment system with Bitbucket's Pipelines for my symfony project.
If you want to use Pipeline you need to use a docker image.
I have configure my pipeline in this way:

```
image: laraedit/laraedit

pipelines:
  branches:
    testing:
      - step:
          script:
              - rm -rf var/cache/
              - composer install
              - mkdir -p ~/.ssh
              - cat my_known_hosts >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts
              - (umask  077 ; echo $MY_SSH_KEY | base64 --decode > ~/.ssh/id_rsa)
              - cp app/config/parameters.yml.test.dist app/config/parameters.yml
              - chmod -R 777 var/
              - export TERM=xterm-256color
              - ./runtest.sh
              # - many other commands
```

When I push on branch `testing` pipelines start and break inside ./runtest.sh with an error 500 (that I can retrieve because is the docker of bitbucket).

Inside ./runtest.sh there is this commands to launch test for my application:

```
rm -rf var/cache/tests/
bin/console doctrine:database:drop --env=test
bin/console doctrine:database:create --env=test
bin/console doctrine:schema:update --force --env=test
bin/console doctrine:fixtures:load --no-interaction --env=test
./vendor/bin/phpunit
```

So I have checked inside Bitbucket documentation and I have found how to test the docker image locally with this command:

```
docker run -it --volume=/Users/my_username/my_site/:/localDebugRepo --workdir="/localDebugRepo" --memory=4g --entrypoint=/bin/bash laraedit/laraedit
```

I have tried locally and when I go inside the docker image with the bash I have make all script commands written inside pipelines so:

```
rm -rf var/cache/
composer install
mkdir -p ~/.ssh
cat my_known_hosts >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts
(umask  077 ; echo $MY_SSH_KEY | base64 --decode > ~/.ssh/id_rsa)
cp app/config/parameters.yml.test.dist app/config/parameters.yml
chmod -R 777 var/
export TERM=xterm-256color
./runtest.sh
```

Magically tests pass!!!
But is the same Bitbucket docker image and I expected that ./runtest.sh will be broken to check the 500 internal error server, but no errort, ./runtest.sh passed and all is good inside my docker image locally (same configuration of the bitbucket docker image).

So  which is the diffrence between my docker image local and Bitbucket docker image if the docker image are the same?

I need to check why ./runtest.sh break but It only breaks inside Bitbucket docker image

Comment: Do you see a log for the commands being executed? Is it possible your tests depend on a webserver being running locally or something?

Comment: Yes I see commands log but don't show me the description of the 500 error. 
Same webserver locally and inside the online server

Comment: maybe for debugging you could add something like `tail var/log/error.log` to your pipelines script

Comment: I have already tried but seems that it doesn't work, tail don't show me any lines

Comment: something must be different though, are you using linked containers locally or anything like that? Do you have files that are excluded from git that are required for your project? You can try to clone your repo in a new folder (which is what pipelines would be using) and do the same debugging process there. Then you can be sure you're using the same files